# Running a simple Spark script on Mesos with Zookeeper

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I want to run a simple spark program, but i am  restricted by some errors.
My Environment is:
CentOS:**6.6**
Java: **1.7.0_51**
Scala: **2.10.4**
Spark: **spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6**
Mesos: **0.22.1**

All are installed and nodes are up.Now i have one Mesos master and Mesos slave node. My spark properties are below:

```
spark.app.id            20150624-185838-2885789888-5050-1291-0005
spark.app.name          Spark shell
spark.driver.host   192.168.1.172
spark.driver.memory 512m
spark.driver.port   46428
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.executor.memory   512m
spark.executor.uri  http://192.168.1.172:8080/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
spark.externalBlockStore.folderName spark-91aafe3b-01a8-4c86-ac3b-999e278807c5
spark.fileserver.uri    http://192.168.1.172:51240
spark.jars  
spark.master            mesos://zk://192.168.1.172:2181/mesos
spark.mesos.coarse  true
spark.repl.class.uri    http://192.168.1.172:51600
spark.scheduler.mode    FIFO
```

Now when I started spark, it comes to scala prompt(scala>).
After that I am getting following error: mesos task 1 is now TASK_FAILED, blacklisting mesos slave value due to too many failures is Spark installed on it
How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

With only 900MB and `spark.driver.memory = 512m`, you will be able to launch the scheduler/REPL, but you won't have enough memory for `spark.executor.memory = 512m`, so any tasks will fail. Either increasing your VM memory size or reducing the driver/executor memory requirements will help you get around these memory limits.

Comment: Do you mean 512m mentioned is applicable to workers also. That means 900-512=388m, could be the cause?

Comment: driver.memory is applicable to where the driver is running, but executor.memory (also 512m) is required in addition to the resources required for your tasks. The executor is what executes the tasks. If you're running the driver and the executor/tasks on the same, single slave node, you'll run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the mesos slave logs/ task information for more output on why the task failed. You could have a look at :5050.

Probably unrelated question: Do you actually have zookeeper:

```
spark.master mesos://zk://192.168.1.172:2181/mesos
```

running (as you mentioned you only have one master)?

Comment: It was just keep repeating TASK_FAILED..5050 is up and running. I want to increase the master so I kept zk. BTW. It was having 900 MB memory available, after increasing it to 2GB, it looks working. So probable memory was the issue!! Thank you..